# getting a bill of use 2-Protocol Hours bill. Does anyone know about these charges in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cost-management

Instantly after transferring data of 1 TB, I am getting a bill of use 2-Protocol Hours bill. Does anyone know about these charges in AWS?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact wording from the bill (copy & paste).

Comment: Please specify the service and usage type. You can find both in the AWS Cost Management service (billing)